# How do I sort a pivot table by certan Grand Total column using VBA?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

This is my code so far, but it doesn't do what I need it to do, which is sort by the grand Total column which is named "Total Sum of RevVarLY".

```
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("3").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("RevVarLY").AutoSort Order:=xlDescending, Field:="Total Sum of RevVarLY"
```

Comment: An image would help.

Answer (score 0):

The Values Fields can only be sorted by the 'natural' groupings formed by the fields to the immediate left. If you only have one row field, then you can do what you want. If you have more, then you can't.